# UITableView wrong images loaded with custom cell and UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I have a problem with the App I'm developing.

I've made a UITableView with custom cells. In the cell I've put a little UIView to show the image of a user (loaded from Data Core) using the method `bezierPathWithRoundedRect:`

When I load the table in the App the images are correct until I make a fast scroll on the table. I think there is a problem with asynchronous loading/editing of the images but I do not know how to solve it. If I use a simple UIImageView in the cell instead of the UIView, everything works correctly.
I've found quite similar questions here but nothing with a UIView class and Data Core loading...

This is the code for my cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)presentTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FellowshipCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [presentTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    ExpenseParticipants *participant = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    IconView *icon = (IconView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    icon.immagine = [UIImage imageWithData:participant.usrImage];


    return cell;
}
```

And this is the implementation of the UIView class (IconView.h and IconView.m) used to draw a round rect with the image of a user:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Draving code
    UIBezierPath *icon = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.bounds cornerRadius:12];

    [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(self.bounds);

    [immagine drawInRect:self.bounds];
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding [inmagine setNeedsDisplay] to force redraw of your custom view

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked!
I've added [icon setNeedsDesplay]; before returning the Cell.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the delay :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should realloc the cell when it is null

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [presentTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if(cell==nil){
    cell = [[UITableView alloc] initWith...]
}
```